# Get data in SSMS from Web API Controller with parameters

Tags: controller, ssms, asp.net-core-webapi

In my case, I need to get data in SSMS from web api controller (using XML-data). Also, need to send some parameter from SSMS to controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSMS: For getting data from controller use in "Shared Data Source Properties" -
Type: XML,

Connection string: https://siteAdress/api/ControllerName/MethodName

In Shared Data Properties - Data source: use data source from the previous step,
Query type: Text,

Query:
[Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boyaJ.jpg)

In Shared Data Properties - Parameters: add a parameter (for example "pUserLodin" with data type - text, without default values).

In Report data - Dataset properties - Query: use a shared dataset from the previous step,

In Report data - Dataset properties - Parameters: initial parameter "pUserLodin",
in my case I set value "=mid(User!UserID , InStr(User!UserID,"")+1)".

In Web API Controller (Inside the method you can use your code, it can show just how to get and send data):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpGet]
    [ReadableBodyStream]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult MethodName()
    {
        string body = string.Empty;
        string userLogin = string.Empty;

        HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            body = stream.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
        }

        if (body != string.Empty)
        {
            userLogin = body.Split('=')[1];
        }

        if (userLogin == string.Empty)
        {
            return GetDefaultData(); // For Shared Dataset only. 
        }

        string stringData = string.Empty;
        var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyType>));
        var stringWriter = new Utf8StringWriter();
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, orgUnits);
            stringData = stringWriter.ToString();
        }

        return Content(stringData, "text/xml", Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public class ReadableBodyStreamAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            // context.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind(); // For ASP.NET 2.1
            context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering(); // For ASP.NET 3.1
        }
    }
```